# Can't call AppComponent function inside ngOnInit : "Object doesn't support property or method"

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript

I'm new to Angular and I'm trying to call my function setCenter2() from the AppComponent class in the ngOnInit function in the same class, is this possible ? When I click on my map, basically when it tries to call my function, (I use OpenStreetMap) I get this error : ERROR TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'setCenter2'. Tell me if you need more of my code, thank you. Do I need to look out for something in particular when doing this ?

I've seen about the bug with internet explorer but it doesn't seem to be this, I'm using Edge and using the latest version of Angular.

```
export class AppComponent {

[…]

setCenter2() {
  var view = this.map.getView();
  view.setCenter(ol.proj.fromLonLat([this.longi1, this.lati1]));
  view.setZoom(this.zoom);
}

[…]

ngOnInit() {

  […]

  this.map.on('click', function (args) {
    console.log(args.coordinate);
    var lonlat = ol.proj.transform(args.coordinate, 'EPSG:3857', 'EPSG:4326');
    console.log(lonlat);

    // var lon = lonlat[0];
    // var lat = lonlat[1];
    //alert(`lat: ${lonlat[1]} et long: ${lonlat[0]}`);
    eval("this.longi1 = lonlat[0];"); 
    eval("this.lati1 = lonlat[1];");

    this.setCenter2();
    alert(`lati: ${this.lati1} et longi: ${this.longi1}`);
  }); 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use fat arrow function because you loose value of `this`:

```
this.map.on('click', args => {
```